# Scale Animation for Image, NOT ImageView

Tags: android

I'm able to do a scale animation on an imageview but the view crops the image when it's set.

I need to accomplish a scale animation on the image itself because scaling down the view reveals the cropped edges

Is this possible without a frame-by-frame animated drawable?

I don't have any code to share because I'm not even sure where to start

Answer (score 0):

You should scale it's bitmap like this:

```java
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
//replace first `120` with your target width and second `120` with your target height
imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 120, 120, false));
```

Comment: thank you so much for this.  However, I'm looking to animate the difference

Comment: @Psest328 you can see [this source code](https://github.com/emrekose26/PinchZoom/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/emrekose/pinchzoom/Touch.java). this is for pinch zoom and it's using the matrix scaling.